# Differenze tra "scaffale" e "mensola"

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning, difference

"Scaffale" e "mensola": questi due vocaboli mi sono sempre sembrati molto simili. Non capisco se ci sono differenze di uso o di significato tra loro. Potreste aiutarmi a chiarire questo mio dubbio?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In sintesi: uno scaffale ha le mensole.

Lo scaffale, infatti, è un mobile di legno o di metallo con dei ripiani orizzontali. Di solito si usa per i libri o per oggetti non troppo pesanti e voluminosi. La mensola, invece, è un piano di legno o di metallo. È possibile anche attaccare al muro una o più mensole singolarmente per appoggiare oggetti da cucina, ad esempio, o di altro tipo.

Comment: Sostanzialmente giusto; ma la mia esperienza differisce per un dettaglio: non ho mai chiamato "mensole" i ripiani di uno scaffale: li chiamo, appunto, "ripiani". Una mensola è solo quella attaccata al muro.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni: Comunque, cercando un po' su Google, ho trovato cose come questa: http://www.ingrocenter.it/scaffale-disney-trilly-3-mensole.

Comment: E una scansìa sarebbe lo stesso di uno scaffale, vero?

Comment: Leggendo il libro *Parola di Dante* di Luca Serianni ho imparato che *mensola* è «tra gli apporti danteschi più notevoli, perché inavvertiti, al lessico attuale».